# CentOS connect to VirtualBox network

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, centos-6

I have created a virtual network by using VirtualBox and I would like to know how can I make CentOS connect to it and have its own IP (e.g. 192.168.1.102 ) because I have a Windows 7 VirtualBox inside CentOS, so I would like to have both communicate with Windows 192.168.1.103.

How can I do this?

[image]

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. Do you have a physical CentOS with VirtualBox, in which you run a virtual Win7?

Comment: Could you run `ifconfig` on the CentOS host and add its output to your question?

Answer (score 1):

As it looks in the provided picture, you have created a host-only virtual network on the CentOS VirtualBox-server, assigned the CentOS ip 192.168.1.1 and told it to act as a dhcp-server for this network.

The Win7 virtual machine has received ip 192.168.1.101 and can talk to the CentOS as it is configured.

Just remember that host-only networks doesn't route traffic, so the Win7 box will not be able to talk to machines outside the virtual network.

Comment: I am trying to find a way for the windows to communicate with the centos, what can I do about this?

Comment: The CentOS host doesn't get 192.168.1.1. That IP is used for the DHCP server on the host-only network.

Answer (score 0):

If VirtualBox is installed correctly, then the host should have a network interface for the host-only network. Some versions of Linux will see the interface and automatically configure it through DHCP.

Try running `ifconfig` on the CentOS host. You should see a host-only interface listed, and it may already have an IP address allocated. In fact, given that the DHCP range starts at .100, and the Windows guest has .101, the host may have 192.168.1.100.

Comment: here's the deal, I have port 3389 open on centos dedicated server so that I can connect and create windows 7 VPS.. then I am trying to connect using port 3391 to win7 RDC vps.. but somehow something is mix up or not correctly setup.. what should I be doing?